# How do you access query arguments in getSelectors() when using createEntityAdapter with RTK Query

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I've been following along the REDUX essentials guide and I'm at part 8, combining RTK Query with the `createEntityAdapter`. I'm using the guide to implement it in a personal project where my `getUni` endpoint has an argument named `country`, as you can see from the code snippet below.

I'm wondering is there anyway to access the `country` argument value from the state in `universityAdaptor.getSelector(state => )` at the bottom of the snippet, as the query key name keeps changing.

```js
import {
  createEntityAdapter,
  createSelector,
  nanoid
} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import {
  apiSlice
} from "../api/apiSlice";


const universityAdapter = createEntityAdapter({})

const initialState = universityAdapter.getInitialState();

export const extendedApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: builder => ({
    getUni: builder.query({
      query: country => ({
        url: `http://universities.hipolabs.com/search?country=${country}`,
      }),
      transformResponse: responseData => {
        let resConvert = responseData.slice()
          .sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
          .map(each => {
            return { ...each,
              id: nanoid()
            }
          });

        return universityAdapter.setAll(initialState, resConvert)
      }
    })
  })
});

export const {
  useGetUniQuery
} = extendedApiSlice;


export const {
  selectAll: getAllUniversity
} = universityAdapter.getSelectors(state => {
  return Object.keys({ ...state.api.queries[<DYNAMIC_QUERY_NAME>]data }).length === 0  
? initialState : { ...state.api.queries[<DYNAMIC_QUERY_NAME>]data }
})
```

UPDATE: I got it working with a turnery operator due to the multiple redux Actions created when RTK Query handles fetching. Wondering if this is best practice as I still haven't figured out how to access the `country` argument.

```js
export const { selectAll: getAllUniversity } = universityAdapter
  .getSelectors(state => {

  return !Object.values(state.api.queries)[0]
    ? initialState : Object.values(state.api.queries)[0].status !== 'fulfilled'
      ? initialState : Object.values(state.api.queries)[0].data
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote that "Essentials" tutorial :)

I'm actually a bit confused what your question is - can you clarify what specifically you're trying to do?

That said, I'll try to offer some hopefully relevant info.

First, you don't need to manually call `someEndpoint.select()` *most* of the time - instead, call `const { data } = useGetThingQuery("someArg")`, and RTKQ will fetch and return it. You only need to call `someEndpoint.select()` if you're manually constructing a selector for use elsewhere.

Second, if you *are* manually trying to construct a selector, keep in mind that the point of `someEndpoint.select()` is to construct "a selector that gives you back the entire cache entry for that cache key".  What you usually *want* from that cache entry is just the received value, which is stored as `cacheEntry.data`, and in this case that will contain the normalized `{ ids : [], entities: {} }` lookup table you returned from `transformResponse()`.

Notionally, you might be able to do something like this:

```js
const selectNormalizedPokemonData = someApi.endpoints.getAllPokemon.select();

// These selectors expect the entity state as an arg, 
// not the entire Redux root state: 
// https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createEntityAdapter#selector-functions
const localizedPokemonSelectors = pokemonAdapter.getSelectors();

const selectPokemonEntryById = createSelector(
  selectNormalizedPokemonData ,
  (state, pokemonId) => pokemonId,
  (pokemonData, pokemonId) => {
    return localizedPokemonSelectors.selectById(pokemonData, pokemonId);
  }
)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding! I've been able to digest and keep up with the material, so kudos to great documentation! It goes a long way. At the bottom of my original snippet I'm attempting to use it similarly to the "Essentials" demo, (Part 8 transforming Responses method) except in my case I had an argument in the getUni `query`.

My apologies about the confusing question. I'm trying to understand how to use the built in getSelectors when using the `createEntityAdapter` with RTK Query. In the documentation it was achieved via `someEndpoint.select()` but maybe there is a better way.

Comment: I know I could technically manipulate it in my component from `{data} = useGetThingQuery("someArg")` but in an attempt to keep my component logic simplified, I wanted to see if it is achievable with the tools in the redux toolkit (certain there is and I'm missing a step). Thanks again for helping out

Comment: Updated my answer with a snippet that I _think_ is along the lines of what you're looking for.  If you're still stuck, I'd suggest coming by the `#redux` channel in the Reactiflux Discord ( https://www.reactiflux.com ) and asking there, and we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Some more info that may help see what's happening with the code in the Essentials tutorial, background - getLists endpoint takes 1 parameter, select in the service:

```
export const getListsResult = (state: RootState) => {
  return state.tribeId ? extendedApi.endpoints.getLists.select(state.tribeId) : [];
};
```

And my selector in the slice:

```
export const selectAllLists = createSelector(getListsResult, (listsResult) => {
  console.log('inside of selectAllLists selector = ', listsResult);
  return listsResult.data;
  // return useSelector(listsResult) ?? [];
});
```

Now this console logs `listsResult` as `ƒ memoized() {` function! Not something that can have `.data` property as tutorial suggests. Additionally `return useSelector(listsResult)` - makes it work, by executing the memoized function.

This is how far I got, but from what I understand, the code in the Essentials tutorial does not work as it is...

However going here https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-chandrasekhar-r4mcn1?file=/src/features/users/usersSlice.js and adding same console log:

```
const selectUsersData = createSelector(selectUsersResult, (usersResult) => {
  console.log("usersResult", usersResult);
  return usersResult.data;
});
```

Shows it is not returning a memorised function, but an object with data on it instead.

Wonder if the difference happening because I have a parameter on my endpoint...

Answer (score 0):

`select` returns a memoized curry function. Thus, call it with first with corresponding arg aka `tribeId` in your case and then with `state`. This will give you the `result` object back for corresponding chained selectors.

```
export const getListsResult = (state: RootState) => {
  return state.tribeId ? extendedApi.endpoints.getLists.select(state.tribeId)(state) : [];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The intention of the `getUni` endpoint was to produce an array of university data. To implement the `.getSelector` function to retrieve that array, I looped over all query values, searching for a `getUni` query and ensuring they were `fulfilled`. The bottom turnery operator confirms the `getUni` endpoint was fired at least once otherwise, it returns the `initialState` value.

```js
export const { selectAll: getAllUniversity } = universityAdapter
  .getSelectors(state => {
    let newObj = {};

    for (const value of Object.values(state.api.queries)) {
      if (value?.endpointName === 'getUni' && value?.status === 'fulfilled') {
        newObj = value.data;
      }
    }

    return !Object.values(newObj)[0] ? initialState : newObj;
  })
```